# how to programmatically get and set the IBM MobileFirst Server address in an app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is there an API in IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation client app libraries to programmatically get and set the full address or URL of the WL server the app is to connect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Starting IBM MobileFirst 6.3 there are new APIs for both Hybrid and Native SDKs to set and get the server URL during app runtime.

See this blog post: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/02/02/changing-server-url-runtime/

Stack Overflow blocks links *to let me google that for you*. ;)

Basically you have two APIs:

`WL.App.getServerUrl(getServerURLSuccess, getServerURLFailure)`

And for example:

```
var serverURL = $("#serverURL").val();
WL.App.setServerUrl(serverURL, setServerURLSuccess, setServerURLFailure);
```

That's it.

Comment: :-)  Thanks Idan.  You know, I searched and searched and did not find that link.  But it is right there.  Maybe I need to go back to google from DuckDuckGo but the latter is so much better, and certainly more secure.

Comment: Please consider adding some code snippets or description of solution. I am in a similar problem and the link is not getting opened.

Comment: The link is opening fine here.

Comment: Its possible our network policy is blocking the link. See It depends on the infrastructure so I request you to edit your answer to be more helpful. Thanks.

Comment: And I request you to put more effort, because this information is available also in official documentation of the product you are using. Clearly, you did not even try looking for it. Edited and added some code. Have fun.